# Why are reported std devs different from measured std devs for lmer random effects and residuals?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

```
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

set.seed(1234)
n_groups <- 100
n_per_group <- c(100, 100, 50, 50, rep(2, 96))
cum_n_per_group <- cumsum(n_per_group) |> lag(default  =0)

a <- 0.3
data <- local({
  group_effect <- rt(n = 100, df = 3)
  x <- runif(n = sum(n_per_group))

  foreach(group_index = seq_along(n_per_group), .combine = rbind) %do% {

    foreach(i_in_group = 1:n_per_group[group_index], .combine = rbind) %do% {
      i <- cum_n_per_group[group_index] + i_in_group
      y <- a * x[i] + group_effect[group_index] + rnorm(1)
      tibble(x = x[i], y = y, g = group_index)
    }
  }
})


m <- lmer(y ~ x + (1 | g) - 1, data = data)
summary(m)

residuals(m) |> sd()
r <- ranef(m)
r$g$`(Intercept)` |> sd()
```

The model equation is $y = a.x + \omega_g + \epsilon$ where $\omega_g$ is the random intercept associated with group $g$.

reported random effect sd: 1.21; measured: 1.05

reported residual sd: 0.92; measured: 0.88

Is there some sort of Bayesian adjustment going on? How do I replicate it?

Comment: 1. I'm pretty good with R but I'm having trouble mentally parsing your code. Please add comments. And include the necessary `library` calls. 2. A model including a random effect (here an intercept) without the corresponding fixed effect is not sensible.

Comment: @Roland, added the library calls and included an equation of the model, which has a fixed effect $a$

Comment: `task 1 failed - "task 1 failed - "object 'cum_n_per_group' not found"`

Comment: sorry, I took that out in the edit because I thought it wasn't used. fixed now.

Comment: The reported value of residual standard deviation is an **estimate** from the REML fit and not from the residuals. See `help("sigma")` and the `"devcomp"` slot of the model object (described in `help("getME")`). Both estimates approach the true value (from the simulation) if you dramatically increase the `n_per_group`, e.g., by a factor of 50. The explanation should be similar for random effects.